# Column value not properly passed to hive udf spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I have created a hive udf like below,

```
Class customUdf extends UDF{
def evaluate(col : String): String = {
return col + "abc"
}
}
```

I then registered the udf in sparksession by,

```
sparksession.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION testUDF AS 'testpkg.customUdf'""");
```

When I try to query hive table using below query in scala code it does not progress and does not throw error also,

```
SELECT testUDF(value) FROM t;
```

However when I pass a string like below from scala code  it works

```
SELECT testUDF('str1') FROM t;
```

I am running the queries via sparksession.Tried with GenericUdf, but still facing same issue. This happens only when i pass hive column. What could be reason.

Comment: Is there any error entry in teh hive logs?

Comment: @MattAndruff there is no error but job not progressing

Comment: can you post the hive log showing what's happening?  It should have somethign in the log

Comment: @MattAndruff I can see another error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : org/apache/hive/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/Kryo

Comment: It would seem your build package is missing libraries it expects.  Perphaps you should examine how you are building the jar, and where it's getting placed in hdfs to see if you can resolve this missing class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing your jar from hdfs:

```
create function testUDF as 'testpkg.customUdf' using jar 'hdfs:///jars/customUdf.jar';
```

Comment: Tried this sparksession.sql("""CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION testUDF AS 'testpkg.customUdf' using jar 'hdfs:///jars/customUdf.jar'""");, but still facing issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about implementation of UDFs in Scala, but when I faced similar issue in Java, I noticed a difference that if you plug in literal

```
select udf("some literal value")
```

then it is received by UDF as a String.
But when you select from a Hive table

```
select udf(some_column) from some_table
```

you may get what's called a [LazyString](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/hive/content/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/lazy/LazyString.html) for which you would need to use getObject to retrieve actual value. I am not sure is Scala handles these lazy values automatically.